# Postgres library for verifying ethereum signatures

Tags: postgresql, ethereum

I'm looking for a function or a library that can verify an ethereum signed message. I just want the signature verification function. Is there one readily available?

Comment: I don't think that helps. I'd prefer an in-db solution, given that there are elliptical curve libraries for postgres.